# php compare/diff an array with an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, compare, diff, laravel

I have 2 PHP arrays, a simple one:

```
array
  0 => int 5
  1 => int 6
```

and an array of objects:

```
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[43]
      public 'id' => int 1
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[46]
      public 'id' => int 3
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[43]
      public 'id' => int 5
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[46]
      public 'id' => int 6
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[46]
      public 'id' => int 7
```

I'd like to make a diff of these 2 arrays to eliminate in the second those present in the first. In this example, i don't want the ids 5 and 6 in the second array. But i need help ;>

Thank you.

fabien

Comment: what version of php are you rolling?

Comment: Version 5.3.8, but it's solved now, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `$objects` is your array of objects, and `$values` is your array of values to remove...

You could use a `foreach` loop if you want to return objects:

```
$values = array(5, 6);
$objects = array(
    (object) array("id" => 1),
    (object) array("id" => 3),
    (object) array("id" => 5),
    (object) array("id" => 6),
    (object) array("id" => 7)
);
foreach($objects as $key => $object) {
    if(in_array($object->id,$values)) {
        unset($objects[$key]);
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://eval.in/31266) (0.008 sec)

If you want to use the `diff` function itself (that's possible but awkward, less readable and will just return an array of values) you can (as Baba suggested) return the `id` of the object inline:

```
$values = array(5, 6);
$objects = array(
    (object) array("id" => 1),
    (object) array("id" => 3),
    (object) array("id" => 5),
    (object) array("id" => 6),
    (object) array("id" => 7)
);
$diff = array_diff(array_map(function ($object) {
    return $object->id;
}, $objects), $values);
```

[Live demo](http://eval.in/31265) (0.008 sec)

Comment: Thank you Babs Seed, that's exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can try :

```
$diff = array_diff(array_map(function ($v) {
    return $v->id;
}, $array2), $array1);
```

[See Live DEMO](http://eval.in/31264)

Comment: This doesn't return an array of objects, it returns an array. Thanks for the eval.in link though, I've never seen that site before.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the second array and use `in_array` method to check for existing values in first

```
$firstArray = array(5, 6);
foreach ($objects as $key => $object) {
    if (in_array($object->id, $firstArray)) {
        unset($objects[$key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For versions older than 5.3

```
 foreach( $arr_2nd as $key => $val  )
{
   $arr_2nd[$key] = $val->id;
}

array_diff( $arr_1st, $arr_2nd );
```